# Delete all rows with a specific name

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete all rows with a specific name. In this example "gerda65".
I can delete one row by doing

```
mDatabase.child("shares")
         .child("senneken-shares")
         .child("1515596541713UjBPLm7rHMXGy6leFhj5H9VTQwh1")
         .child("gerda65")
         .removeValue();
```

But I want to delete all the gerda65 values under my "senneken-shares".

Here is my firebase db structure:
[image: This is my firebase database structure]

Does anyone how to do that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for that, since they allow proper data filtering. You would do something like:

```
var ref = mDatabase.child("shares")
         .child("senneken-shares");    
var query = ref.orderByChild("gerda65").equalTo(true);
```

This will return a list of all the "gerda65". So you need to add a listener to read this data, iterate through it, getting their keys and deleting them:

```
query.once('value', function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(snap){
        ref.child(snap.key).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: The removeValue() had to be changed to just remove() but it works!